# powershell select-object property AND expandproperty

Tags: powershell, select-object

Trying to execute a Select-Object, but i can't seem to return property and a value from a key-value list property.  There are 3 properties i want returned RunStart, Message and 'tableName' from this Parameters property.

I get too much with this:

```
|Select-Object -Property Parameters,RunStart,Message

Parameters                                    RunStart              Message
----------                                    --------              -------
{[tableName, AHROR012], [schemaName, dbo]...} 11/14/2019 5:39:06 PM Operation on target failed
```

But I dont get the RunStart or Message when i do this:

```
|Select-Object -ExpandProperty Parameters -Property tableName,RunStart,Message

Key                 Value
---                 -----
tableName           AHROR012
```

How do i do it to get:

```
Parameters.tableName                         RunStart              Message
----------                                    --------              -------
AHROR012                                      11/14/2019 5:39:06 PM Operation on target failed
```

THANKS!!!

Comment: instead of using `-ExpandProperty`, use a calculated property.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
... | Select-Object -Property @{
      Name='ParametersTableName';
      Expression={ $_.Parameters.tableName }
    }, RunStart, Message
```

Answer (score -2):

A more elegant solution would be to use a 2nd `select` statement:

`... | select RunStart,Message -ExpandProperty Parameters | Select RunStart,Message,tableName`